# How do I find where the Java Development Kit is installed?

Tags: java, scientific-linux

I installed the JDK on Scientific Linux 7. How can I find the location of the JDK where it was installed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is for RHEL6, but that should be close enough for government work:

```
$ rpm -qa | egrep -i jdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85-2.6.1.3.el6_7.x86_64
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.36-1.13.8.1.el6_7.x86_64
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc-1.6.0.36-1.13.8.1.el6_7.x86_64
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.36-1.13.8.1.el6_7.x86_64
$ rpm -ql java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85-2.6.1.3.el6_7.x86_64
...
```

Where the `-ql` for a particular RPM should show what files have been installed.